# range of POSIXct dates in lists

Tags: r, list, posixct

Consider this list of POSIXct dates:

```
times <- list(as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 00:30", "2012-07-26 6:20",
                           "2012-07-26 10:40", "2012-07-26 15:50")),
              as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 01:15", "2012-07-26 10:10",
                           "2012-07-26 15:15", "2012-07-26 18:50")),
              as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 00:35", "2012-07-26 15:05", 
                           "2012-07-26 19:36", "2012-07-26 22:32")),
              as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 03:34", "2012-07-26 16:43", 
                           "2012-07-26 21:44", "2012-07-26 23:45")))
```

If I do:

```
range(times[[1]])
```

I correctly get:

```
[1] "2012-07-26 00:30:00 CEST" "2012-07-26 15:50:00 CEST"
```

Now, if I do:

```
range(times[c(1,3)])
```

for whatever reason R decides to convert the POSIXct objects into timestamps and gives me

```
[1] 1343255400 1343334720
```

I then try to reconvert them to POSIXct by doing:

```
as.POSIXct(range(times[c(1,3)]), origin="1970-01-01 00:00")
```

And, strangely, I get the range with 1 hour of advance:

```
[1] "2012-07-25 23:30:00 CEST" "2012-07-26 21:32:00 CEST"
```

So I have to do:

```
as.POSIXct(range(times[c(1,3)]), origin="1970-01-01 01:00")
```

To get the correct range of:

```
[1] "2012-07-26 00:30:00 CEST" "2012-07-26 22:32:00 CEST"
```

Am I missing something or is there a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`times[[1]]` is a vector, while `times[c(1,3)]` is a list.  Convert the latter to a vector before calling `range` and all is well.

You don't want to use `unlist` though, since it will only return an atomic vector (`range` must be doing something like that internally), but you can use `do.call`:

```
range(do.call(c,times[c(1,3)]))
```

The differences you get from using `as.POSIXct` are likely due to timezone issues.

Comment: A quick look at `range.default` confirms that it first calls `c(...,recursive = TRUE)` on it's arguments.

Answer (score 2):

As Joshua said, the hour is because of timezones. Try, for example:

```
times <- list(as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 00:30", "2012-07-26 6:20",
                       "2012-07-26 10:40", "2012-07-26 15:50"), "GMT"),
          as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 01:15", "2012-07-26 10:10",
                       "2012-07-26 15:15", "2012-07-26 18:50"), "GMT"),
          as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 00:35", "2012-07-26 15:05", 
                       "2012-07-26 19:36", "2012-07-26 22:32"), "GMT"),
          as.POSIXct(c("2012-07-26 03:34", "2012-07-26 16:43", 
                       "2012-07-26 21:44", "2012-07-26 23:45"), "GMT"))
as.POSIXct(range(times[c(1,3)]), origin="1970-01-01 00:00", "GMT")
```

Comment: You can also change the date of your environment instead with :`Sys.setenv(TZ='CEST')` if you wanted to work with CEST dates.

Comment: When I do that, I get the following warning after trying to create times: `Warning message:
In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'CEST'`. Is it a problem with my R installation (or do I need additional packages maybe)?

Comment: Seems to work now. Is there a reason it didn't work the first time round? It's also reporting times in "GMT", not "CEST" (even after setting TZ)... Thanks for the solution though, it's much simpler!

Comment: It's probably safer using `Sys.setenv(TZ='Europe/Berlin')` or another city, as many abbreviations are used for different time zones. See `Sys.timezone()` for more info, and enjoy the fun of time zones.